# Finding Submodules

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, modules

Let     $G= ( \mathbb{C} ^3, A)$ be the $\mathbb{C}[x]$-module given by 
$$
       A=\left(\begin{matrix}
        0 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        1 & 0 & 0 \\
        \end{matrix}\right).
$$
I'm trying to show that there are precisely three submodules of dim 1.

Also that $G$ can be generated by a single vector.

So far I've calculated $A^3=I$ so then maybe the submodules have basis $v,Av,A^2v$ not sure what to do next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint;:the submodules of dim 1 correspond to the eigenvalues/eigenspaces

Comment: Could G be generated by the vector (1,1,1) ?

Comment: $A(1,0,0) = (0,0,1)$, $A^2(1,0,0)= A(0,0,1) = (0,1,0)$. Thus $G$ is generated by $(1,0,0)$

Comment: Thank you, I've found the eigenvalues $1^{1/3}$ I don't follow how they correspond to the submodules